# Magento 2: disable system warning messages in Admin Panel for some user

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, messages

[image]

Is there a way to disable system warning messages popups for some specific user (or for all users also) in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

Login to your Admin

Navigate to:

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced
```

Disable Admin Notifications by

```
Disable Modules Output > Magento_AdminNotification > Set to Disable
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. You solution works, but it disable notifications for all users.. If it is possible, I would like to disable them only for specific users.

Comment: Does not work since Version 2.2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197280/magento-2-2-cant-find-how-to-disable-module-from-back-end

Answer (score 1):

Create a new role here if you have not created already **System->User Roles->Role Resources**
If you have already created it then do the following
**System->User Roles->Role Resources** (tab) from **Resource Access** drop down under **system** folder tree find the **Other Settings** now you can see **Notifications** you may **enable/disable**here save the role and assign this role for specific users.

[image: see the pic]

Comment: It doesn't works as you described.. Notifications are always showed, also for the new role, if I just disable the "Notifications" resource.. But it works if I disable all the "System" resource for the new role. Moreover, if I disable only the "Cache Management" resource, the notification about the cache will not be showed anymore... Do you know how it works exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use user-role specific handles from this module https://github.com/TheFrankman/magento2-customhandles (very handy anyway) 
and then remove the block via layout:

```
<referenceBlock name="notification.messages" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Until a proper fix can be rolled out, I created a userscript to fix this problem using Tampermonkey. For those that do not know what Tampermonkey is, it is a userscript manager browser extension, that allows users to install scripts that make on-the-fly changes to web page content after or before the page is loaded in the browser.

Here is the script
https://github.com/EnochDataSystems/gists/blob/master/magento2-system_messages-fix.js

The script will reduce the width of the systemMessageBlock and move it to the top left corner. When the systemMessageBlock is loaded, it will hover over any text or elements in that corner, but after 5 seconds it will fade away.

This is an easy quick fix and doesn't involve touching the Magento code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using magento2 (2.4.1-p1 version).
I have disabled the module output for my backend with this command:

php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminNotification

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the module output for my backend with this command:
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_AdminNotification