# Magento 2.2 Cant find how to disable module from back end

Tags: magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2 I can't find a way to disable module. It was use to be under configuration > Admin but it's not there anymore..

Can someone please help me out.thanks

Comment: This settings is removed from M2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Magento 2.2 disable module section has been removed,

> The ability to disable module output has been removed from Admin. If
>   you disabled module output from Admin in a previous release, you must
>   manually configure these settings. See Disable module output for
>   details.

[image]

For more Info visit this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html)

Comment: I am trying to disable review built-in extension but it's giving me error

Comment: What is the reason for it? Magento need complex our life? I don't understand what is the reason to remove these type of features from Admin panel

Comment: How to disable all modules in single change?

Answer (score 1):

This has been removed from Magento 2.2

From the command line, you can use:

`bin/magento module:status` to list all active and inactive modules

Find your module name, and use this to disable it:

`bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module`

Or use this to fully uninstall the module:

`bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_Module`

Answer (score 1):

Edit `app/etc/config.php` and add:

```
'advanced' =>
 array (
  'modules_disable_output' =>
   array (
    'Magento_Review' => '1',
 ),
)
```

Here is the official Magento [tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that although they removed this functionality from admin, old values still exists on core_config_data & they still has effect on the modules (Bug?).
Anyway, if you disabled modules from admin, you can use phpmyadmin or other methods to re-enable them on core_config_data:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM  `core_config_data` 
>   WHERE  `path` LIKE  '%modules_disable_output%'

*In the future, use Magento CLI to enable/disable modules:

> bin/magento module:status
>   bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
>   bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to disable the module in Magento 2:

**Method 1:**

You can do it via command line, go to the root directory of your store and run these commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module
```

**Method 2:**

You can also do it via config.php file, go to app/etc directory of your store and open the config.php file. Here you will see the list of all the installed extensions on your store. Just replace the code of your extension:

From `'Vendors_Module' => 1` to `'Vendors_Module' => 0`

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Magento 2.2.0 and I use to disable a module via Admin panel by doing below few steps.
Go to Admin panel

1. **System > Web Setup Wizard**
2. Choose "**Module Manager**" task[image]
3. Select action **Disable / Enable** on relevant Module[image]