# Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced Not showing up

Tags: cron, backend, magento2.2

I'm trying to set up a custom cron job as per [this tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html), but `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced`does not exist on my backend.

This is what the Advanced menu looks like for me:
[image: This is what the Advanced menu looks like for me.]

This is what step 2 (before any code) the tutorial thinks it should look like:
[image: This is what step 2 (before any code) the tutorial thinks it should look like.]

Was that tab removed in 2.2?

Comment: Post your code what you have done so peoples can understand

Answer (score 0):

Please add below files in your custom module for custom cron:-

**Path: \Vendor\SampleModule\Cron\AddItem.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SampleModule\Cron;

use Vendor\SampleModule\Model\ItemFactory;
use Vendor\SampleModule\Model\Config;

class AddItem
{
    private $itemFactory;

    private $config;

    //add your dependency here        
    public function __construct(ItemFactory $itemFactory, Config $config)
    {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //you can add your logic here
        if ($this->config->isEnabled()) {
            $this->itemFactory->create()
                ->setName('Scheduled item')
                ->setDescription('Created at ' . time())
                ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Path: \Vendor\SampleModule\etc\crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendorAddItem" instance="Vendor\SampleModule\Cron\AddItem" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Please check your cron job using below command:-

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu item ***Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced*** seems to have been removed in Magento 2.2 together with the functionality to disable modules:

[Magento 2.2 Cant find how to disable module from back end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197280/magento-2-2-cant-find-how-to-disable-module-from-back-end)

I've been searching for it, too - but no chance to find it.