# How do I target a class in the Model directory of a custom plugin with crontab in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

As the title suggests I'm having some trouble targeting three custom classes I want to run on a schedule. The crontab.xml below returns the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'NameSpace\Module\PHPFileWithMyClass' not found in /var/www/domain.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
```

crontab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="job-name" instance="NameSpace\Module\PHPFileWithMyClass" method="execute" >
            <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/config_path_works/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job>
        <job name="job-name2" instance="NameSpace\Module\PHPFileWithMyClass2" method="execute" >
            <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/config_path_works/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job>
        <job name="mjob-name3" instance="NameSpace\Module\PHPFileWithMyClass3" method="execute" >
            <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/config_path_works/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job> 
    </group>
</config>
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
NameSpace
-/Module/
--/etc/
---crontab.xml
--/Model/
---PHPFileWithMyClass.php
---PHPFileWithMyClass2.php
---PHPFileWithMyClass3.php
```

Comment: Please make the the name unique for each cron and check in schedule cron table

Comment: It looks like your classes are not `NameSpace\Module\PHPFileWithMyClass` but `NameSpace\Module\Model\PHPFileWithMyClass`. Correct `crontab.xml` and make sure namespace in php classes is correct  (including `Model` part).

Comment: @PurushotamSharma, I'm sorry, that was my mistakes. In my code the job names are unique. In the cron table they're showing that the class can't be found.

Comment: @Zefiryn, I'm the front end developer trying to troubleshoot a back end issue. My back end developer told me that "Model" should be omitted from the class name?

Comment: Please check my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207480/stores-configuration-advanced-advanced-not-showing-up

Comment: @Zefiryn you were correct. Model is supposed to be included. It's running now. Thank you.